# Iterating Through Tuples Produced by NLTK Pos Tagger

Tags: python, nltk

I have tagged sentences like this:

```
[[('paid', 'VBN'),
  ('$', '$'),
  ('400', 'CD'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('supplier', 'VB')],
 [('bought', 'VBD'),
  ('iphone', 'NN'),
  ('for', 'IN'),
  ('$', '$'),
  ('1100', 'CD')]]
```

I am passing one sentence from this list at a time (like process(sentence[1])) to this function:

```
def process(sentence):
    effect = 'credit'
    amount = 0
    ac = 'na'
    for tup in sentence:
        if (tup[1].find('NN') != -1):
            ac += ' '+ w1
        elif (tup[1].find('CD') != -1):
            amount = w1
        elif (tup[0] in debits):
            effect = 'debit'
    print(ac, amount, effect)
```

But getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-869edd588202> in <module>()
----> 1 print process(sentence[1])

<ipython-input-124-63459fe42a43> in process(sentence)
      4     ac = 'na'
      5     for tup in sentence:
----> 6         if (tup[1].find('NN') != -1):
      7             ac += ' '+ w1
      8         elif (tup[1].find('CD') != -1):

IndexError: string index out of range
```

My main idea with this function is that for each sentence it takes, it should look at all tuples it has, if a tuple's tag (*tup[1] in code*) is 'NN' we store it in *ac*, and so on. Help appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is with where you are calling it.  When I define your array at the top to be `sentences = [[...` then I call `process(sentences[1])` I do not get the error described

Comment: I am surely doing that. Here's my source code in jupyter notebook if you'd like to see [link](https://files.fm/u/pchx5eps)

Comment: Nope - I got "NameError: name 'sentence' is not defined". Then I changed to `sentences[1]` and it ran fine

Comment: Are you trying to exact words with NN tags?